# dnx : Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'ef'

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, entity-framework-core

I am using using `ASP.NET 5` Beta 8  with `Entity Framework 7` Beta 8

I created a new class Library Package.

I ran the following install packages prompts:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServer -Pre
Install-Package EntityFramework.Commands -Pre
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework -Pre
```

My `project.json`

```
{
 "version": "1.0.0-*",
 "description": "MARS Class Library",
 "authors": [ "myname" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },
  "dependencies": {
     "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
     "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
     "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8",
  }
}
```

In my package manager console I navigate to my `src\project` directory in which the `project.json` is located and run any `dnx` `ef` command e.g.:

```
dnx ef migrations --help
```

or

```
 dnx ef migrations add InitialMigration
```

However I get the following error:

> dnx : Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'ef'.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - dnx ef migrations --help
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: Unable t...e command 'ef'.:String) [], RemoteException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

I have a DBContext class and model classes but the error seems to be related to not being able to understand they keyword `ef` at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solution:

Add the `ef` command to your `project.json`

```
   "commands": {
      "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    }
```